# How do I "Look Me Up By Email"

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

I am making an iOS application and I would like to use the iCloud feature "Look Me Up By Email" found under iCloud in the Settings of iOS.

I would like to simplify the user experience by identifying users by their iCloud so they don't have to remember a login for my app.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand this, this is a CloudKit feature related to `CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation`. You can discover people from your contacts with the same app and can be discovered by them. You need to request permission for that ability first, like this:

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().requestApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.UserDiscoverability) { [unowned self] (status, error) -> Void in
   //Your code handling error or success...
}
```

**Note**

Release notes for iOS 10 mention, that this operation and related functions will be changed. In iOS 10+ you need to use `CKDiscoverAllUserIdentitiesOperation`

**Example of usage**

init a container first, note that your container `accountStatus` must be correct

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.YourContainerID")
```

Later, ask a permission

```
container.requestApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.userDiscoverability) { [unowned self] (status, error) -> Void in     
   if let err = error {
      print(err)
   }
   else if status == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.granted{
      //success
   }
   else{
      print("Permission not granted")
      print(status)
   }
}
```

Later, you can get your current user record id and create a subscription for example (note that you don't need a permission and user record ID to create a subscription, but in my case it was needed to create a predicate):

```
container.fetchUserRecordID { [weak self] (recordID, error) in

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user = %@",userRecordID.recordName)
    let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "myRecordType", predicate: predicate, options: CKSubscriptionOptions.firesOnRecordCreation)

    container.publicCloudDatabase.save(subscription, completionHandler: { (subscription, error) in 
        //completion stuff here
    }
}
```

Friends discoverability example

```
let discoverOperation = CKDiscoverAllUserIdentitiesOperation()

var users = [CKUserIdentity]()

discoverOperation.discoverAllUserIdentitiesCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (error: Error?) -> Void in

   if let err = error as? NSError{
      print("Discover Friends Error: \(err)")
   } else {    
      //do whatever you want with discovered contacts
   }
}

discoverOperation.userIdentityDiscoveredBlock = { (userIdentity: CKUserIdentity) -> Void in
   users.append(userIdentity)
}

discoverOperation.queuePriority = Operation.QueuePriority.high //this option is up to your tasks
container.add(discoverOperation)
```

Comment: I can't find any docs for the "Look me up" iCloud setting in Apple Docs, do you have a link to explain it or what's the point of discovering contacts with iCloud emails ?

Comment: do you have any sample tutorial for this feature ?

Comment: @JAHelia The point is that you can give your users an ability to communicate with their friends that's already the app's users too. How and why would you do that is the other question. In my opinion this feature is almost abandoned now, it's highly limited also.

Comment: @JAHelia occasionally I have my old code for this feature. It's on Swift v.3 or v.2.